# Does Elixir have a language specification?

Tags: elixir

Does Elixir have a language specification document? If yes, where is it?

The Elixir website has [library documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html), and I found some documentation on [guards](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/guards.html) and [operators](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/operators.html), but I did not find a language spec that, for example, documents syntax or provides a list of Elixir keywords (Elixir language keywords, not [Keyword lists](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html)).

Comment: I strongly suspect it's the same case as with ruby. "This is the reference implementation. What it does __is__ elixir"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no formal specification. Here are some things to look at, that describe the language and might be useful:

- [Syntax Reference](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/syntax-reference.html#content) - available only in master docs.
- [Kernel.SpecialForms](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#content) - these are the things that are provided "by the language" and cannot be changed - more or less like keywords in other languages. Everything else is macros/functions implemented in Elixir.
- [Kernel](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#content) - this module is imported by default and can be viewed as the "base" of the language - everything from here can be locally changed by importing, though.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about the Syntax Reference.

Comment: Syntax Reference appeared in Elixir documentation in version 1.9.4: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.9.4/syntax-reference.html. So the latest release version documentation https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/syntax-reference.html has this now. Indeed, that is an awesome resource in clarifying how Elixir works.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax Reference is the best place to get specification.

Actually I am looking for atom, but found in spec missing mention this:

These are atom too:

```
:/
:.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just recently switched from Eiffel to Elixir. Eiffel has an outstanding language specification document ([see link](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/ECMA_Standard_367)). This is a BNF-E and is written extremely well. The language is excellent for a 1980s OO, but it is not the power of Elixir by any stretch. Still–the way I became an Eiffel expert was by reading and understanding the language rules (BNF-E specification). It taught me how to "Think like my compiler".

I now want to do the same for Elixir ([see here](https://github.com/ljr1981/elixir_bnfe/blob/main/README.md)), as I am moving on into this exciting new language system. However, I am finding documentation that is very surface, but nothing that tells me what my choices are from the compilers point of view. To do that, I need to language specification.

The closest I can find so far is found on [Github (here)](https://github.com/otakbeku/elixir-bnf), but it is poorly made. I would love to find a company that would be willing to work with me to build such a language specification for Elixir and then a training program built on top of that!